Can identical example and source blocks be made to look different in a PDF export?
I use both #+begin_src and #+begin_example blocks in my org-mode markup that gets exported to PDF. If I put identical text in to these blocks, then they look identical in the PDF export. Is there any way to change that? For example, can I make #+begin_example blocks export with a background colour that is not shared by my #+begin_src blocks?

For source code blocks there is the package engrave-faces, but, unfortunately it works only for full buffer; for region is still a work in progress. An interesting alternative here.
